# Do the continuation created by `call/cc` and the continuation used for making a call to a function in CPS both make jump?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, continuations, continuation-passing

When a continuation is called as a procedure, does some jump occur?

For example, I have seen two use cases of continuation:

1. Are the continuation created by `call/cc` and the continuation used
   for making a call to a function in CPS the same concept, and do both involve jump?
2. When a continuation captured by a `call/cc`  call is called, the
   program execution flow will jump to the `call/cc` call.
3. When a function in CPS is called with a continuation, does similar
   jump also occur? (I am not sure)

   For example,

   ```
   (letrec ([f (lambda (x) (cons 'a x))]
            [g (lambda (x) (cons 'b (f x)))]
            [h (lambda (x) (g (cons 'c x)))])
     (cons 'd (h '())))   (d b a c)
    can be written in CPS as

   (letrec ([f (lambda (x k) (k (cons 'a x)))]
            [g (lambda (x k)
                 (f x (lambda (v) (k (cons 'b v)))))]
            [h (lambda (x k) (g (cons 'c x) k))])
     (h '() (lambda (v) (cons 'd v))))
   ```

   `(lambda (v) (cons 'd v))` is a continuation passed to `h`, then to
   `g` and `f`, before it is eventually called. But when it is called,
   is there any jump also occurring?

Comment: Every call can be seen as a jump with closure structure so it doesn't jump more than usual. CPS can be seen as internal structure of a language so the continuation is how flow continues and the program never returns. The last continuation is `halt`

Comment: *not* the same. CPS *contingencies* are normal functions, tail-called -- there's no jumps, just normal tail call optimization (it's no more a jump than a normal function call is a jump, per "lambda is the ultimate goto"). `call/cc`-created continuations are more like `longjmp` from C. a source file's compilation can involve whole-program CPS transformation to *emulate* the true continuations.